# How to install: Quandl on Anaconda (Python) 3.4 on OSX

Tags: python, macos, installation, quandl

I cant figure out for the life of me how in the world to install How to Quandl on Anaconda 3.4 on OSX.

I have tried using: `pip install quandl`, I have tried moving files around and opening the `setup.py` file and I keep getting a syntax error. It is extremely annoying that I cant get this done even after a ton of googling. I would greatly appreciate it someone out there who has done this could please clue me in on how to install `quandl`. Thanks.

Comment: Could you include the error dump? It's pretty hard to debug "I keep getting a syntax error".

Comment: For what it's worth, `pip install quandl` works perfectly for me (Anaconda 2.1.0, Python 3.4.1, Win7 x64)

Comment: I typed "pip install quandl", in the console and it outputted  " pip install Quandl
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

"

Comment: Where can I locate the error dump so I can provide more information?

Comment: I placed file "Quandl-2.8.5.tar.gz" into my working directory, is the where it should be when I do the install using pip install quandl? Is there a way to install it from the directory that I have it in rather than the web? I am at a loss here as to how to get this to work.

Comment: What do you get if you run `pip --version`? Are you sure you have pip installed?

Comment: Scratch that - Anaconda comes with setuptools installed - but are you sure pip is in your path ie you can actually run it?

Comment: Yes pip seems to be working I am able to call its member functions like pip.absolute_import etc....But still not luck on the 'pip install quandl'  unfortunately. I do not know how to make sure that pip in is my path however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is indeed to type

```
pip install Quandl
```

However this simply needs to be typed in the OSX terminal or command prompt and **NOT** in the Anaconda workspace!

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Anaconda has the install
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/quandl

From that page, to install this package with conda run:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda quandl
```

Comment: Or simply `conda install quandl`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using anaconda:

```
conda install pip
```

Else:

```
pip install quandl
```

Comment: no clue why two commends are shown in one line. But everybody should get that they are two commends, right?

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have luck running the 2to3 command in terminal. Run

```
2to3 *.py
```

in the main project folder and any subdirectories containing .py files.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following at the appropriate command prompt:

```
conda install quandl
```

hope it works !